# SVG pattern not repeating

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm playing around with SVGs and was working off of [this](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/grid2.svg) example. However, in my 
[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dajix) the pattern isn't repeating for my `<rect>` elements.
And when I change the height and width attributes (no I'm not changing the x , y attributes) the `rect` svg objects just disappear when I enter in large values.
I'm just dipping my toe into SVGs so my knowledge is quite limited. I figure it is something simple but am not seeing what I'm doing incorrectly when I compare to what I'm doing to the [grid2.svg](http://srufaculty.sru.edu/david.dailey/svg/grid2.svg) that I'm going off of.

Answer (score 2):

You've written this...

```
<pattern id="OvalPattern2" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="70" height="70" >
```

With objectBoundingBox units 1 is the size of the shape using it. So your pattern is 70 times the size of the object using it. I suspect you want .7 as the width/height.

Comment: I changed the width/height on the pattern to 0.7, but for a rect of width/height of 140/70, I'd expect the pattern to repeat 2x. It isn't doing this. I'm getting whitespace in between the repeated patterns. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you want the pattern to repeat twice then it's width/height must be 0.5

Comment: Hmm I think I'm confused and need a greater grasp of the difference between `patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"` and `patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"`  and usage of patternContentUnits. Switching to using userSpaceOneUse is solving the pattern auto repeating instead of worrying about sizing the pattern so it repeats the correct # of times in an element. As it stands my use case will have a set pattern repeat indefinitely. http://jsbin.com/dajix/2 <-- this jsbin shows me partially to where I want to be. I want that second `<rect>` to have the pattern start anew in it.

Comment: With "objectBoundingBox", the value "1" represents the width (or height) of the element.  So if width="0.5" and height="1" the fill would consist of two copies of the pattern (side-by-side).  For width="0.5" height="0.5" you would get four copies of the pattern in a 2x2 arrangement.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense. However, I'm still struggling with getting that second `<rect>` to show the pattern and have the pattern start new inside the rect. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" too and adjust the pattern contents to use those units.

Comment: I've added the `patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"` but am unclear what adjustments to make to the pattern contents that you suggested. From my current understanding, using `patternUnits="objectBoundingBox"` I can set how many times the  pattern is repeated in an object via the width/height. Using `patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` the pattern fills the object ad nauseum. Do I need to adjust the x/y attributes on the pattern so that it is positioned the way I want? Then I would need 1 pattern definition for each object that had a diff x/y pos which doesn't seem right.

Comment: patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" means that the pattern content elements have to have positions between 0 and 1.

Comment: So I want the pattern to be as such: `<pattern id="pu_USOU-pcu_OBB-units_Normalized" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
         patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"
x="0" y="0" width="1" height="1" >
  <rect x="0" y="0" height="0.70" width="0.70" fill="#9a4"/>
  <circle cx="0.35" cy="0.35" r="0.25"  style="fill:blue"/>
  <circle cx="0.55" cy="0.50" r="0.07" fill="#b07" stroke-width="0.04" stroke="#a80"/>
    </pattern>` ? Because that isn't working http://jsbin.com/dajix/6  I've tried all iterations of patternUnits, patternContentUnits and normalizing/not normalizing the units to no avail.